# Neo4j: how to find connected nodes with mutual connections nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
MATCH (n), (n)-[:connected_to {status: 2}]-(sp:StayPal)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[:connected_to {status: 1}] - (mutual_friend)-[:connected_to {status: 1}]-(sp)
WHERE (ID(n) = {ID_n})
RETURN DISTINCT sp, collect(mutual_friend)
```

I am trying to fetch all connection of n(staypal) having status = 2 and also with that all mutual connection of n and sp, but I am getting wrong results

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location of the WHERE clause is significant, as it applies to the preceding clause. Place it under your MATCH, not the OPTIONAL MATCH.

Remember that the behavior of OPTIONAL MATCH is to find a match, and if no match is found (including if the OPTIONAL MATCH's WHERE clause evaluates to false), then the newly introduced variables will be set to null.

Also, there's no need to have the match to (n) apart from the pattern match. Just use `MATCH (n)-[:connected_to {status: 2}]-(sp:StayPal)` for the first line.

Comment: Thanks @invserFalcon